# error The argument type 'List<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to do the sum by taking the model that I had made but the results were like.
has anyone ever had a similar case and how to solve it.

> this is the function that I made to do the addition with the type
> String parameter because in the API the data type is string.

```
  totalCalculate<NilaiMahasiswa>(nilaiAkhirUas, String nilaiIndeksAkhir) {
    int nilaiAkhirUas = int.parse(["nilay_akhir_uas"]!);
    double nilaiIndeksAkhir = double.parse(["nilay_akhir"]!);
    return nilaiAkhirUas + nilaiIndeksAkhir;
  }
```

and this is when I call the result of the sum above or in the function above but an error occurs

```
Flexible(
              child: FutureBuilder<NilaiMahasiswa>(
                future: Services().getNilaiMahasiswa(semester),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Text(
                      // 'IPK ${snapshot.data!.data?.first.updatedBy}',
                      'IPK $totalCalculate',
                      style: bold5,
                    );
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    print(snapshot.data);
                    return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                  }
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                },
              ),
            ),
```

> and this is the error message that is displayed

[image]

Comment: You have directly parse data with key,

Try this:- int.parse(nilaiAkhirUas["nilay_akhir_uas"]!);

Comment: still error
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Type'.
Try defining the operator '[]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to parse int from List
`int.parse(["nilay_akhir_uas"]!)` . Actually this will raise error. Maybe you just like to read the map, I guess the map is `nilaiAkhirUas`.  So it is safe to `.tryParse`

```dart
  totalCalculate<NilaiMahasiswa>(nilaiAkhirUas, String nilaiIndeksAkhir) {
    int nilaiAkhirUas = int.tryParse(nilaiAkhirUas["nilay_akhir_uas"]??"")??0;
    double nilaiIndeksAkhir = double.tryParse(nilaiAkhirUas["nilay_akhir"]??"")??0;
    return nilaiAkhirUas + nilaiIndeksAkhir;
  }
```

Or if those  parameters are string, you can do

```dart
  totalCalculate<NilaiMahasiswa>(nilaiAkhirUas, String nilaiIndeksAkhir) {
    int nilaiAkhirUas = int.tryParse(nilaiAkhirUas??"")??0;
    double nilaiIndeksAkhir = double.tryParse(nilaiIndeksAkhir)??0;
    return nilaiAkhirUas + nilaiIndeksAkhir;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`int.parse` expects `String` not `List of String` so,

```
  totalCalculate<NilaiMahasiswa>(nilaiAkhirUas, String nilaiIndeksAkhir) {
    int nilaiAkhirUas = int.parse(nilaiAkhirUas);
    double nilaiIndeksAkhir = double.parse(nilaiIndeksAkhir);
    return nilaiAkhirUas + nilaiIndeksAkhir;
  }
```

Should work

Comment: The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

and
The argument type 'double' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Comment: Just adjust the numbers you put on 'parse'. They both expect String. If you have double, there is no need to parse it to double again

Answer (score 0):

maybe you wanted to do this:

```
 totalCalculate<NilaiMahasiswa>(nilaiAkhirUas, String nilaiIndeksAkhir) {
    int nilay_akhir_uas = int.parse(nilaiAkhirUas);
    double nilay_akhir = double.parse(nilaiIndeksAkhir);
    return nilay_akhir_uas + nilay_akhir;
  }
```